# Java Swing: Resize JMenuItem's icon, either automatically or programatically?

Tags: java, swing, resize-image

It seems that JMenuItems don't automatically resize any image icon that's assigned to them, and from what I can tell, there isn't a property that makes them automatically do that, either.

Is anyone aware of a way that I can programatically resize the Icon for a JMenuItem? It seems like the Icon object is lacking functionality as it is, unless there's some other function that can actually deal with Icon objects.

Comment: Given that such functionality would a) encourage developers to distribute 400(+)x400(+) 'icons' with their apps., and b) there are a great many algorithms to resize an image, I am glad Sun/Oracle never added such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the class and override it's paint method to resize the image before painting.

Comment: I was actually hoping on getting some sort of image object back, where as the paint method for Icon doesn't return anything, and it just... paints.

Comment: You could easily cache the resized image and return it as you desired.

Comment: Make it a member of the extended class. When you paint it, determine if the cached picture is the size you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Image class' method
public Image getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints) to scale to desired size.